# How to let two animations for UIView executed one by one

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, uiview

I have a small UIView and want to let it move to center of screen first, and then, zoom to full screen.
But when I begin start an animation like

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animation1" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(showDetailToFullscreen)];
self.currentDetailVC.frame = centerFrame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

And in the same controller, I have a method:showDetailToFullscreen

```
- (void)showDetailToFullscreen {
    CGRect screenFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animation2" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    self.currentDetailVC.view.frame = screenFrame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

but when start, it still executed together.
I think the problem they are still in the same transaction. But how can I let these two animation executed one by one? Appreciate for any answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead of the setAnimationDidStopSelector:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(showDetailToFullscreen) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
```

Comment: Great job, It's good enough solution for my app, I've tested, and no matter write this line in between animation begin and commit or write it after animation committed, it works well, thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

It's now considered much better to annimate views using the 'blocks' methods that can be found in the "Animating Views with Blocks" section in the [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).

In most of these methods you can specify a "completion" block of code that can be used to start off a second animation when the first animation completes. You could also call `showDetailToFullscreen` within this completion block.

I'd reccommend trying this method instead.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, that's good way, the problem is my app must be compatible with 3.2 iOS, so, I can't use block:), and I tested Easen's solution, it's OK, and can be worked in 3.2.2. Any way, I should say thanks for your help:)

Comment: Ah ok that's cool. I think Easen's solution is also a good one so long as the value of 0.5 is made into an understandable variable (like `firstAnimationDuration`)! :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you targetting iOS 4 or later? If so, I recommend using the block-based animation methods instead. What you want to do is very easy:

Example from UIView docs:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
     animations:^{view.alpha = 0.0;}
     completion:^(BOOL finished){ [view removeFromSuperview]; }];
```

Comment: Yep, same with suggestion from James, I worked in 3.2, so, thanks for your help:)